# How to check if an array contains elements?

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods, element

I'm new to Java.

I have an array that looks like this [(Array)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VcpY.png). (I've used Array.toString to print this). This is how the array is made: [arraymade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxI3G.png).
And this is read and made from a file in this format:

```
Nilsson;Lars;u;g;vg;vg
Svensson;Lena;vg;g;g;vg
Jonsson;Jonas;g;g;vg;g
```

I'm trying to make a method that returns either "u", "vg" or "g" depending on what the objects array contains.

```
@Override
public String getKursbetyg() {



    if (Arrays.asList(uppgiftsbetyg).contains("u")) {
        kursbetyg = "u";
        return kursbetyg;

    } else if (Arrays.asList(uppgiftsbetyg).contains("if the array contains 2 vg strings")) {
        kursbetyg = "vg";
        return kursbetyg;

    } else {
        kursbetyg = "g";
        return kursbetyg;
    }

}
```

This is the code I have now but it doesn't seem to work as it only returns "g" even though the array contains "u".

Also as you can see I want the method to only return vg when 2 vg:s are found because you need 2 vg:s to get the grade vg. So how do I check for double elements here ?

Comment: is it a 1-D or 2-D array ?

Comment: The image you of the arrays shows 3 different arrays, [u, g, vg], [vg, g, g], [g, g, vg], which array are you using? Can you show us where you set uppgiftsbetyg?

Comment: I added a pic how the array is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should rethink your requirements. The presence of one string (like `u`) does not preclude the absence of the others (like two `vg`s or a `g`) nor does the absence of `u` and two `vg`s prove the presence of a `g`. Your posted examples are already inconsistent in this regard.

Besides that, your method lacks a declaration of the variable `kursbetyg` and I really hope, you are not modifying a field as a side effect of this “get…” method.

You can search for two occurrences straight-forward by searching a sublist excluding the first occurrence:

```
public String getKursbetyg() {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(uppgiftsbetyg);
    if(list.contains("u")) {
        return "u";
    }
    int index=list.indexOf("vg");
    if(index>=0 && list.subList(index+1, list.size()).contains("vg")) {
        return "vg";
    }
    return "g";
}
```

a solution closer to your original structure, which also might be considered simpler is

```
public String getKursbetyg() {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(uppgiftsbetyg);
    if(list.contains("u")) {
        return "u";
    } else if(Collections.frequency(list, "vg")>=2) {
        return "vg";
    } else {
        return "g";
    }
}
```

But it might do more work than necessary by unnecessarily counting occurrences of `vg` beyond `2`.